# Ruby on Rails MySQL to SQLite export/dump

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Is it possible to export or dump a MySQL database that can be easily imported into SQLite? The export would be initiated by the logged in user of the application so a command line script probably wouldn't be feasible here. Any suggestions or gems that can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly it's possible, I don't specifically how, but but you should be able to find the answer you're looking for at http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-export-a-mysql-database-to-json-csv-and-xml-with-ruby-and-the-activerecord-gem give that a read and you can setup a script in your lib directory and call it from a controller action

Comment: Looks cool. Thanks Cyle I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [yaml_db](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) gem.

With this gem you can dump the data from MySQL and load to SQLite.

Comment: OP doesn't want to have to do it in the command line he wants to do it during runtime.

Comment: Well, Rails is perfectly capable of executing arbitrary command line instructions. (A few ways are documented here: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands). Not saying there isn't a better way, but it should work.